# Strange characters returned after screen scraping using Ruby/Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, screen-scraping, nokogiri

I'm using Ruby and Nokogiri to scrape data off a client's legacy system.

The text I'm getting contains a trademark symbol.  But when I display it on the console or save it to the database, the TM gets converted to a different character.

`Diet™` BECOMES `Dietâ¢`

I'm pretty sure it's just an encoding problem and I'm pretty sure Ruby has an easy way to deal with it, but after several minutes of googling and trying a few obvious options, I'm not any closer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the encoding of the originally scraped data? Also please show us what you've tried.

Comment: "[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an encoding mismatch, but you haven't told us enough to help you.

Things to check:

- What encoding does the server say their page is? It'll be in the HTTPD headers returned.
- Is the document *REALLY* encoded as the server says, or are there characters that are not in that codeset?

Typically, you'll get documents as UTF-8, ISO-8859-1 or Win-1252, so try using those values to give Nokogiri a hint. The documentation for `Nokogiri::HTML.parse` says:

```
parse(thing, url = nil, encoding = nil, options = XML::ParseOptions::DEFAULT_HTML, &block)
```

Where:

> encoding is the encoding that should be used when processing the document.

One way to figure out what the server is sending back is:

```
require 'open-uri'
open('http://www.example.net') { |io| io.charset }
# => "iso-8859-1"
```

Warning: What the server sends back is not necessarily what the content really is, so it's only a preliminary hint. The document returned could be anything, and at that point you're on your own to figure out what it is.

Typically we use `Nokogiri::HTML('some html to parse')`, but you can use:

```
Nokogiri::HTML('some html to parse', nil, 'UTF-8')
```

Look at Ruby's Encoding to figure out what the available codesets are:

```
Encoding.constants
```